# Triangulating Position vs. GPS on Phone Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, gps, geolocation, location

I am trying to write an application that will gather the location of the user from a JavaScript. I currently am debugging from a laptop using the Geolocation API, and it is proven to work for a given amount of time. It broadcasts my location every few seconds and then will recalculate when I move after a 5-10 seconds. This has proven to use a lot of my battery/cpu for some reason. If I were to use this app on a phone, will it broadcast my position via GPS or triangulate it's position from local cellular towers?

```
var latitude, longitude, accuracy, angle;
function setGeolocation(prevID) {
var geoID = window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(getPosition,handleErrors,{maximumAge: 1000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
//Pass the ID's to the seeMyGeoID function.
seeMyGeoID(geoID,prevID);
function getPosition(position){
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
    angle = position.coords.heading;
    console.log(latitude+"  "+longitude+"  "+accuracy+"  "+angle);
};
function handleErrors(err){
    if (err.code == 1){
        console.log("PERMISSION_DENIED");
    }
    if (err.code == 2){
        console.log("POSITION_UNAVAILABLE");
    }
    if (err.code == 3){
        console.log("TIMEOUT");
    }
};

};

function seeMyGeoID(geolocationID,previousID){
if(geolocationID != previousID){
    previousID = geolocationID;
    //Wait 1 second.
    setTimeout(function(){
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(previousID);
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(previousID+1);
        setGeolocation(previousID);
    },1000);
}

};

//Call function for the first time.

setGeolocation(0);


//I want this code to be able to take a position every 0.5-1 second, or in real time (but that may be pushing it).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your choice in the `enableHighAccuracy` option, and it depends on the phone's browser implementation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions.enableHighAccuracy

Different implementations interpret "high accuracy" in different ways. It just means the browser would try to get high accuracy even if it needs to sacrifice battery and takes long time. How high is high enough isn't determined by you. You won't have the control over whether it's GPS or Wi-Fi/cellular triangulation. The implementation decides that for you.

Getting geolocation always costs battery life. If `watchPosition` costs too much for you, you can consider using `getCurrentPosition` with your own strategy.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't had the capability to debug/test it from a phone yet. I'm trying to understand how to direct the implementation so that it uses the GPS as it's first choice so that compiling speed and battery life aren't as much of a burden (hopefully). Thank you, Chen